# Move an Item from a Parent Folder to its Subfolder

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a script that will move a file/files from a parent folder into its subfolder.  That's it.  I have seen scripts that will move files up into their parent folders, but nothing for moving them down one peg.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is the subfolder a predictable name, or can it vary essentially randomly?

Comment: The subfolder is always the same name, and it resides within a folder on the Finder

Answer (score 1):

Why get complicated.

```
cd /Users/admin/Desktop/test &&
mkdir -p Archive &&
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -nv {} Archive \;
```

Pros:

- Handles spaces, special characters, or even newlines in filenames correctly.
- Exits if it can't get to the `test` directory.
- Exits if the `Archive` directory doesn't exist and can't be created.
- Tells you what files it's moving.
- Doesn't overwrite existing files with the same name.
- Is actually a one-liner, just broken up for readability:

  ```
  cd /Users/admin/Desktop/test && mkdir -p Archive && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -nv {} Archive \;
  ```

Answer (score -2):

It's not perfect but the following will mostly work. Assumptions:

• The source directory is /Users/admin/Desktop/test (can be edited)

• The nested destination directory is Archive

```
#!/bin/bash

oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(/bin/echo -en "\n\b")

dir="/Users/admin/Desktop/test"

if [ -d $dir/Archive ] ; then
    for FILE in `/bin/ls $dir | /usr/bin/grep -v Archive` ; do
        /bin/echo "Moving $FILE"
        /bin/mv $dir/$FILE $dir/Archive/$FILE
    done
    else
        /bin/echo "Folder $dir/Archive does not exist"
fi

IFS=$oldIFS
```

Note that if you have other files with "Archive" in the name they'll be skipped, too.. I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: 1. [Don't parse `ls`.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943)  Just never do it.  2. [Quote your shell variables.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)  3. [`printf` is better than `echo`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943), particularly when you need to use escape sequences.

Comment: WOW!  Thanks, all!  I'll work with these today and see how it goes!

Comment: lol- I have a long way to go.. Thanks for the tips!